# VSTO customization not loading on user PC

Tags: vb.net, vsto

Its a long story. I had a simple VSTO excel solution that i build in VS 2005 and Excel 2003. Few years ago we upgraded to Excel 2010 and VS2010. The VSTO solution was upgraded to .xlsm file and everything worked fine.

Recently we upgraded to Office 2013 and VS2013. (Office 2010 was uninstalled and then Office 2013 was installed). I opened the VSTO project and it forcibly upgraded the solution. I published the new version which created the setup.exe in the publish folder. I install the new customization on my dev PC and then open the .xlsm file that was installed on c:\user\abc\appdata\local...  on my dev machine and everything works fine.

However, when i install setup.exe on a user machine and open the .xlsm file, even though i dont get any errors, the customizations (buttons etc) are all greyed out. Its as if it didn't even install. I banged my head with this all day today and cant figure it out. PLEASE HELP.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tarun,

Make sure that all the required prerequsites were installed properly. See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx) for more information.

Also I'd suggest checking the COM Addins list in the application. Is it enabled?

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again. See [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) for more information.